# How to remove PVC nut sandwich

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

Pictured below is the drain for a tub that I need to take apart (to fish out a rubber drain stopper that fell down).

I don't understand what was done in the PVC area (or what these things are (called)) and how to undo it so that I can take it apart.

What should I loosen to undo this and in what order?  It seems like PN.a and PN.b are in eachother's way and neither can be loosened.

Is it likely that there is a pipe between `PN.a` and `PN.b` that I cannot see and both of these nuts are slip fittings over that pipe?  (This is a clawfoot tub to it's possible they lowered it)

`CP.a` and `CP.b` slip into `CT.a` and I cannot simply undo `CN.a` and `CN.b` and remove them (as it's not a union joint).

[image: plubming under tub]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd try a shop vac sooner than taking that mess apart.  Chances are you breaking something and putting it back together you'll need teflon tape and pipe dope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the nuts should be slip fittings, though PN.a is odd, and may actually be capturing the end of a flanged-end slip tube stuck into PN.b - usually on a plastic drain tee that's just a slip-tube extension of the tee, but given a metal drain tee it might well be different. Image search appears to confirm that likely difference.

[image: thumbnail of a flanged-end slip from supplyhouse.com, which does not seem to work for anything but thumbnails.]

You have to remove the overflow and drain shoe (the "tub ends" of CP.a and CP.b) to get freedom to move things for further disassembly. That involves unscrewing parts **inside** the tub. Then you loosen CN.a and CN.b and those parts can be pulled out (which may be all you need to get your stopper) at which pont you are free to rotate and pull on the drain tee to get it to come up from where it's slipped into PN.b (which you may loosen with an adequately sized wrench, leaving PN.a alone, but letting it be pushed by PN.b if it's jammed tightly.)